# I want to update data into database related to key using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner and I am trying to update the data into a database related to key but unfortunately, it's not working and I have already made the database table I want to update data related to key but I am confused  how to do this please if you have an idea please help me thanks.

**database table**

```
          setting table
          https://ibb.co/crg5H1R
```

**Controller**

```
              public function settingupdate(Request $request)
              {
                  $image = $request->file('logo_image');
                  $contact_number=$request->get('contact_number');
                  $email=$request->get('email');
                  $location=$request->get('location');
                  $facebook=$request->get('facebook');
                  $twitter=$request->get('twitter');
                  $linkedin=$request->get('linkedin');  

                  $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();  
                  Storage::disk('cms')->put($image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension, 
                  File::get($image));
                  $content = new Settings;
                  $content->image = $image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;

                  $check = Settings::where('key', $content->id)
                      ->update(['value' => $content->image,
                                'value'=>$contact_number,
                                'value'=>$email,
                                'value'=>$location,
                                'value'=> $facebook, 
                                'value'=> $twitter,
                                'value'=> $linkedin]);

                return back()->with('success', 'Setting Successfully updated')
                             ->with('path', $check);

             }
```

**HTML view**

```
               <form method="post"  action="{{route('update.setting')}}"   >     
                @csrf
                    <div class="card-box">
                    <div class="panel panel-heading">
                    <h3>Update Settings</h3>
                    </div>        
                     <div class="col-lg-5">
                     <div class="mt-3">
                     <input type="file" name="logo_image" class="dropify"  />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 mt-3">
                     <div class="group-form">
                     <label>Contact Number*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact_number"     class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-lg-5 mt-3">
                    <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Contact Email *</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-lg-10 mt-3">
                    <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Location *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-lg-5 mt-3">
                    <h3> Social Links:</h3>
                    <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Facebook *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="facebook" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-lg-5 mt-5">
                    <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Twitter *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="twitter" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mt-3">
                    <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Linkedin *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="linkedin" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-lg-7 mt-3">
                    <div class="group-form ">  
                    <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect 
                     waves-light col-lg-2">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    </div>   
                    </div> <!-- end card-box -->
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `Settings::where('key', '=', $content->id)` or `Settings::whereKey($content->id) `

Answer (score 0):

I think in your setting table you should add 1 more field "type".
after that you can query all settings and loop it. While you loop you can compare key and update it. I attached the code below:

```
    public function settingupdate(Request $request) 
    {

        $settings = Settings::all();
        foreach($settings as $setting) {
            // check if request have same key in settings table
            if ($request->has($setting->key)) {
                // if setting is image like LOGO, BACKGROUND_IMAGE etc
                if($setting->type == 'image') {
                    $image = $request->file($setting->key);
                    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();  
                    Storage::disk('cms')->put($image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension, 
                    File::get($image));

                    $setting->value = $image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
                } else {
                    // type might be string or number etc
                    $setting->value = $request[$setting->key];
                }

                $setting->save;
            }
        }

        return back()->with('success', 'Setting Successfully updated')->with('path', $check);
    }
```

You can also use DB transaction for multi save too. you can read more [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#database-transactions).

Comment: @Zubair i just update it. you can try again. also did you add type in field your table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use file in your form, you should use **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form tag. Like this:

```
<form method="post"  action="{{route('update.setting')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
    <!-- your codes -->
</form>
```

This code is **wrong** :

```
update(['value' => $content->image,
            'value'=>$contact_number,
            'value'=>$email,
            'value'=>$location,
            'value'=> $facebook, 
            'value'=> $twitter,
            'value'=> $linkedin]);
```

because, you use 'value' for every fields.

Also, you can use this code in your controller :

```
$img = $request->file('logo_image');

try{
    $setting = new Setting();
    $setting->email = $request->email;    // $setting->email : email is your field name in DB
    $setting->location = $request->location;
    $setting->facebook = $request->facebook;
    $setting->twitter = $request->twitter;
    $setting->linkedin = $request->linkedin;
    $setting->contact_number= $request->contact_number;
    if (isset($img)) {
        if (!file_exists('file/' . $id)) {
            mkdir('storage/file/' . $id, 0777, true);
        }
        $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
        $imageName = $currentDate . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $new->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $new->move('file/' . $id, $imageName);
        $setting->image=$imageName;
    }
    $setting->save();


    return back()->with('success', 'Setting Successfully updated');
}catch(\Exception $e){
    Log::error($e); //use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
    return back()->with('error', 'error text');
}
```

And use **protected $fillable** in your **Model** .

Good luck.